# If $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$, is $X+Y$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here we define $X+Y$ as the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ of the form $x+y$ where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.

So suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two distinct lines in $\mathbb{R_3}$. Then $X+Y$ is the sum of these two lines, which yields a single line in $\mathbb{R_3}$. I'm not sure why this should show that $X+Y$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$, because it seems like $X+Y$ can span the same plane as $X$ and $Y$ can together.

Comment: Isn't the sum of two vector spaces also a vector space? (I'm trying to say that I don't think your example of $X+Y$ not being a subspace is correct). Are you trying to prove or disprove the statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces, then the [One-Step Vector Subspace Test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test) can easily be used here.

First, note that $\mathbf 0\in X+Y$ so $X+Y\neq\varnothing$.

Let $u,v\in X+Y$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Then $u=u_X+u_Y$ and $v=v_X+v_Y$ for $u_X,v_X\in X$ and $u_Y,v_Y\in Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces the One-Step Vector Subspace Test implies that $u_X+\lambda\cdot v_X\in X$ and $u_Y+\lambda\cdot v_Y\in Y$. It follows that
$$
u+\lambda\cdot v=u_X+u_Y+\lambda\cdot(v_X+v_Y)=(u_X+\lambda\cdot v_X)+(u_Y+\lambda\cdot v_Y)
$$
so that $u+\lambda\cdot v\in X+Y$. Hence $X+Y$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.

However, if $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily subspaces, then it's quite easy to see that $X+Y$ is not a subspace. For example, if $X=\{(1,0)\}$ and $Y=\{(0,1)\}$, then $X+Y=\{(1,1)\}$ which is not a subspace since $\mathbf 0\notin\{(1,1)\}$.